# How do you draw a Direct2D canvas on to a TcxImage Canvas?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, direct2d

I have an Direct2D demo that creates a GridPatternBitmapBrush then draws the grid pattern on a TForm in a paint method.  How do you get the Direct2D GridPatternBitmapBrush to appear on a TcxImage.Canvas( DeveloperExpress TImage) insead of the form?

```
procedure TFormAdvGeometries.Create_FRadialGradientBrush;
var
//  aGradientStops: array of TD2D1GradientStop;
//  aGradBrushProps: TD2D1RadialGradientBrushProperties;
//  aGradStopsCollection: ID2D1GradientStopCollection;

  gradColors: array of TColor;
begin
  SetLength(gradColors, 3);
  gradColors[0] := TColor($00D7FF); // Gold (D2D1Helper.h)
  gradColors[1] := TColor($00A5FF); // Orange (D2D1Helper.h)
  gradColors[2] := TColor($0045FF); // OrangeRed (D2D1Helper.h)


  // this is a place-holder.
  // Code below assumes equal spread for positions in gradient stops
  FRadialGradientBrush := d2dCanvas.CreateBrush(
    gradColors,
    D2D1PointF(330, 330),
    D2D1PointF(140, 140),
    140,
    140
    );
end;

procedure TFormAdvGeometries.Create_FGridPatternBitmapBrush;
var
  gridBrush: ID2D1SolidColorBrush;
  bmpBrushProps: D2D1_BITMAP_BRUSH_PROPERTIES;
  bitmapRenderTarget: ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget;
  bmpSize: D2D_SIZE_F;
  gridBitmap: ID2D1Bitmap;
begin
  bmpSize.width := 10;
  bmpSize.height := 10;
  d2dCanvas.RenderTarget.CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(
    @bmpSize, nil, nil, 0, bitmapRenderTarget);
  bitmapRenderTarget.CreateSolidColorBrush(
    D2D1ColorF(0.93, 0.94, 0.96, 1), nil, gridBrush);
  bitmapRenderTarget.BeginDraw;
  bitmapRenderTarget.FillRectangle(Rect(0, 0, 10, 1), gridBrush);
  bitmapRenderTarget.FillRectangle(Rect(0, 0, 1, 10), gridBrush);
  bitmapRenderTarget.EndDraw;
  bitmapRenderTarget.GetBitmap(gridBitmap);
  bmpBrushProps.extendModeX := D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP;
  bmpBrushProps.extendModeY := D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP;
  bmpBrushProps.interpolationMode := 0; // could be 1
  d2dCanvas.RenderTarget.CreateBitmapBrush(
    gridBitmap, @bmpBrushProps, nil, FGridPatternBitmapBrush);
end;

procedure TFormAdvGeometries.CreateDeviceResources;
begin
  Create_FRadialGradientBrush;
  Create_FGridPatternBitmapBrush;
end;

procedure TFormAdvGeometries.Paint;
var defMatrix: TD2DMatrix3x2F;
begin
  inherited;

  CreateDeviceResources;

  d2dCanvas.BeginDraw;
  try
    d2dCanvas.RenderTarget.GetTransform (defMatrix);

    // fill with white color the whole window
    d2dCanvas.RenderTarget.Clear(D2D1ColorF(clWhite));

    // fill canvas with little blue rectangles
    d2dCanvas.Brush.Handle := FGridPatternBitmapBrush;
    d2dCanvas.Rectangle(0, 0, ClientWidth + 50, ClientHeight + 50);

    // reset standard transformation
    d2dCanvas.RenderTarget.SetTransform (defMatrix);
  finally
    d2dCanvas.EndDraw;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If I remember, TCxImage.Canvas is a wrapper, containing a "real" canvas inside, something like TCxImage.Canvas.Canvas....  it might be just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the constructor of the d2dCanvas.

Currently it's

```
  d2dCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Handle);
```

which is passing the forms handle to create the canvas.

I don't have Delphi 2010 (Which it seems is shipped with required units for the demo) but I think

```
  d2dCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(MyTcxImage.Canvas.Canvas, Rect(0,0, MyTcxImage.Width,MyTcxImage.Height));
```

should do the trick

You'll need to pass Canvas.Canvas to this constructor because the cx components (at least my version of) use a TcxCanvas which contains a TCanvas.

You may be able to pass the Window Handle of the TcxImage Control to the Direct2DCanvas constructor.

Comment: By using your suggested constructor the canvas is visible in the cxImage, but only when resizing the form. When Resizing the form the canvas appears then disappears. When I release the mouse button the image is empty with nothing visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use d2dCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(cxImage1.Handle); as the constructor the Direct2DCanvas appears in the cxImage. When resizing the form, the  TDirect2DCanvas remains visible.  When you open an image with cxImage the image also appears but is only visible when resizing the form.

I was hoping to be able to do a simple image painting app using the TDirect2DCanvas but I am not sure if this is possible.